# How to optimize an if statement inside a switch statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, interface, switch-statement

I was wondering if it's possible to optimize this code below so that I don't have to have an "if" statement within each case statement? To reduce/minimize code...

FYI - the if statements switch between passing in a production interface (ex. ARMProduction.WebServiceAWI) and a production object (ex. new ARMProduction.User())
and they are coming from different interfaces, so I don't think I can create an interface and pass it.

```
switch(claimParams.ServiceName) {
case "ARM":
    if (_environment.Production)
       claimResult = await WebService<ARMProduction.WebServiceAWI>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.ARMUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new ARMProduction.User());     
    else
       claimResult = await WebService<ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.ARMUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new ARMDevelopment.User());
    break;
case "BW":
    if (_environment.Production)
       claimResult = await WebService<BWProduction.WebServiceBW>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.BWUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new BWProduction.User());     
    else
       claimResult = await WebService<BWDevelopment.WebServiceBW>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.BWUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new BWDevelopment.User());
    break;
case "CS":
    if (_environment.Production)
       claimResult = await WebService<CSProduction.WebServiceCS>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.CSUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new CSProduction.User());     
    else
       claimResult = await WebService<CSDevelopment.WebServiceCS>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.CSUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new CSDevelopment.User());
    break;
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary<string, Func<Task<ClaimResult>>>`

Comment: Hi. Could you please provide a more complete example?

Comment: You have simple decision tree, in the current sample with it size and complexity I would keep it as it is. But if you found yourself continuously changing it by adding/removing new cases or new environments, then you probably can move changeable parts to dedicated structure where adding and removing them will not require to change decision logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.

I think the best way to "optimize" this (as you put it) would be to make it as readable as possible. It's already difficult to read and bugs have a way of finding a home in such areas of code.

So, no, I don't recommend trying to get fancy and use conditional operators or anything that would make the code any less readable than it already is.

Personally, I kind of prefer it if the if statement is removed from the switch statement. This code should be equivalent, but I think is slightly more readable:

```
if (_environment.Production)
{
    switch(claimParams.ServiceName)
    {
        case "ARM":
            claimResult = await WebService<ARMProduction.WebServiceAWI>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.ARMUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new ARMProduction.User());     
            break;
        case "BW":
            claimResult = await WebService<BWProduction.WebServiceBW>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.BWUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new BWProduction.User());     
            break;
        case "CS":
            claimResult = await WebService<CSProduction.WebServiceCS>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.CSUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new CSProduction.User());     
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    switch(claimParams.ServiceName)
    {
        case "ARM":
            claimResult = await WebService<ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.ARMUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new ARMDevelopment.User());
            break;
        case "BW":
            claimResult = await WebService<BWDevelopment.WebServiceBW>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.BWUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new BWDevelopment.User());
            break;
        case "CS":
            claimResult = await WebService<CSDevelopment.WebServiceCS>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.CSUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new CSDevelopment.User());
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of C# 7, you can use the `when` clause in a `switch` statement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause)

This would look something like:

```cs
switch (claimParams.ServiceName)
{
    case "ARM" when _environment.Production:
        claimResult = await WebService<ARMProduction.WebServiceAWI>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.ARMUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new ARMProduction.User());
        break;
    case "ARM" when !_environment.Production:
        claimResult = await WebService<ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.ARMUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new ARMDevelopment.User());
        break;
    case "BW" when _environment.Production:
        claimResult = await WebService<BWProduction.WebServiceBW>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.BWUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new BWProduction.User());
        break;
    case "BW" when !_environment.Production:
        claimResult = await WebService<BWDevelopment.WebServiceBW>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.BWUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new BWDevelopment.User());
        break;
    case "CS" when _environment.Production:
        claimResult = await WebService<CSProduction.WebServiceCS>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.CSUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new CSProduction.User());
        break;
    case "CS" when !_environment.Production:
        claimResult = await WebService<CSDevelopment.WebServiceCS>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.CSUrl, _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new CSDevelopment.User());
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to cut down on code, as @Fabio mentioned, you can use a Dictionary. This can be set up as a composite key with the ServiceName and Production flag.

Something like:

```
var claims = new Dictionary<(string, bool), Func<Task<ClaimResult>>>();
claims.Add(("ARM", true), () => WebService<ARMProduction.WebServiceAWI>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.ARMUrl, 
        _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new ARMProduction.User()));
claims.Add(("ARM", false), () => WebService<ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI>.GetClaim(claimParams, _environment.ARMUrl, 
        _environment.TrustOnlineUsername, _environment.TrustOnlinePassword, new ARMDevelopment.User()));
var claimResult = await claims[(claimParams.ServiceName, _environment.Production)].Invoke();
```